# Unreachable statement error in a method/ confused as to why

Tags: java

Hi I'm writing a method to prompt the user to enter in some values. I want to store these values and return an array to the program.
This is the code I've written

```
public static int[] readInQuarters(String[] firstName, String[] lastName)
{//method to read in quarters
    int[] quarter1= new int[firstName.length];
    int[] quarter2= new int[firstName.length];
    int[] quarter3= new int[firstName.length];
    int[] quarter4= new int[firstName.length];

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<firstName.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter the 1st quarter figure(to the nearest million) for %s %s :",firstName[i], lastName[i]);
        quarter1[i]= input.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<firstName.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter the 1st quarter figure(to the nearest million) for %s %s :",firstName[i], lastName[i]);
        quarter1[i]= input.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<firstName.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter the 2nd quarter figure(to the nearest million) for %s %s :",firstName[i], lastName[i]);
        quarter2[i]= input.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<firstName.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter the 3rd quarter figure(to the nearest million) for %s %s :",firstName[i], lastName[i]);
        quarter3[i]= input.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<firstName.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter the 4th quarter figure(to the nearest million) for %s %s :",firstName[i], lastName[i]);
        quarter4[i]= input.nextInt();
    }

    return quarter1;
    return quarter2;
    return quarter3;
    return quarter4;
}
```

It comes up that return quarter1 and the others is an unreachable statement error. I'm confused as to why?

Comment: when you return you exit the method... so return quarter2; can't be reached

Answer (score 0):

you can only write one return statements and return statement should be the last line of a method.So when you are writing `return quarter1;` then all statements after this line will be not reachable

Have a look at this [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) for more info on returning value from method

Answer (score 0):

A method will only ever run one `return` statement; once that has been run the others will be ignored. If you want to return four items you'll have to put them into some kind of container object, e.g. an `int[]`. That might look something like this:

```
return new int[][]{quarter1, quarter2, quarter3, quarter4};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only able to return one value, with a single return statement. As soon as you use `return`, the method is exited and nothing more will be reached.

If you wish to return multiple values, consider using an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

`return quarter1` will stop the method and return the value.

If you need to return multiple values, you can wither create a class to hold all values

or

if all values are of the same type you can use an `Array` or a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the control switches back to the calling method right after the first return statement

```
return quarter1; // only this is effective
return quarter2; // these are never reached
return quarter3;
return quarter4;
```

Try this

```
int[] arr = new int[4];
arr[0] = quarter1;
arr[1] = quarter2;
arr[2] = quarter3;
arr[3] = quarter4;
return arr;
```